# How to call a button click event when i click another button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 buttons in my win app.

Button1 do a task :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    String[] a = textBox7.Text.Split('#');
    progressBar1.Maximum = a.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        ansh.Close();
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}
```

Button 2 do following

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
        textBox7.Text += item.Contains("@") ? string.Format("{0}#", item.Split('@')[0]) : string.Empty;
}
```

I just want to use just one button for two events.

But I want the event of button2 to be called before event that was called by button1.

Means I want to use just one button instead of button 1 and 2.and when I click I want first thing to be done is getting listbox items in a textbox.

```
{
    foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
        textBox7.Text += item.Contains("@") ? string.Format("{0}#", item.Split('@')[0]) : string.Empty;
}
```

and then the event of starting progress bar and closing connection x.

```
progressBar1.Value = 0;
String[] a = textBox7.Text.Split('#');
progressBar1.Maximum = a.Length;
for (var i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    ansh.Close();
    progressBar1.Value++;
}
```

Comment: A good solution would be to extract the functionality into methods and call the methods inside the button handlers. This way you don't need to fire the click event, but to call a method. Is is also easier to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the logic from behind the click events into separate methods.

```
private void MethodOne()
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    String[] a = textBox7.Text.Split('#');
    progressBar1.Maximum = a.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        ansh.Close();
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}

private void MethodTwo()
{
    foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
        textBox7.Text += item.Contains("@") ? string.Format("{0}#", item.Split('@')[0]) : string.Empty;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MethodTwo();
    MethodOne();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MethodTwo();
}
```

In my experience, it's easier to maintain and test this way. Having different controls' events all calling each other makes it tougher to follow the logic.

Answer (score 14):

You can use **PerformClick** method of button object

```
    Button button1 = new Button(), button2 = new Button();
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* .................... */
        button2.PerformClick(); //Simulate click on button2
        /* .................... */
    }

    void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* .................... */
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that PerformClick will not always work. For example, if "CanSelect" is false (because the button is not visible, for example) PerformClick will do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger the click event of `Button2` manually:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(sender,e);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you neen events:

```
Button1.click += method1;
Button1.click += method2;


void method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do your stuff
}
void method2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do your stuff
}
```